# chocolatey timed out waiting for the command to finish. [METEORJS]

Tags: meteor, chocolatey

Just for a trial I got my hands dirty installing Meteor 1.6 using Chocolatey.

When I ran the command 'choco install meteor', after little time, I receive error below

```
Downloading meteor 64 bit
  from 'https://packages.meteor.com/bootstrap-link?arch=os.windows.x86_64'
Progress: 48% - Saving 83.27 MB of 171.74 MB                                   C
hocolatey timed out waiting for the command to finish. The timeout
 specified (or the default value) was '2700' seconds. Perhaps try a
 higher `--execution-timeout`? See `choco -h` for details.
The install of meteor was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\meteor\tools\chocolateyinstal
l.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 1/2 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - meteor (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\meteo
r\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, Chocolatey has a command timeout of 45 minutes (2700 seconds) as documented here:

https://chocolatey.org/docs/chocolatey-configuration#general

Is the download of the meteor installer taking longer than this?

If so, you can change the value using a command similar to this:

```
choco config set --name <nameFromBelow> --value <value>
```

i.e. in your case (again, as an example):

```
choco config set --name commandExecutionTimeoutSeconds --value 5400
```

Or, if you only want this timeout to apply to a single command, you can try:

```
choco install meteor --execution-timeout 5400
```

As mentioned in the error output.

Comment: Thanks @Gary for your valuable time. I tried `choco install meteor --execution-timeout 10000`, but many other errors comming up lol